# Search For Multiple Properties by Value Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

How can we design a cassandra model for storing a group say 'Item' having n properties P1,P2...PN and 
retrieve the item by searching the item property by value

For Example

```
Item  Item_Type   State  Country

Item1  Solid      State1 Country1
```

In traditional `RDBMS` we can issue a select query

```
select Item from table where Item_Type='Solid' and Country='Country1'
```

How can we achieve such a model in `NoSql Cassandra`,we have tried cassandra secondary index but it seems to be not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

For properties P1..PN you will have to `ALTER` the table as with RDMSs or use an outdated thrift protocol based API (i'd suggest Astyanax for this) which can add columns on-the-fly (but this is considered bad practice). Another possibility is to use a collection of properties where one of your columns is a collection of values:

```
   CREATE TABLE item (
       item_id text PRIMARY KEY,
       property set<text>
   );
```

For `SELECT`ing values with multiple `WHERE` clauses you can use secondary indexing or if you know what columns are going to be required in the WHERE clause you can use a [composite key](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/post/composite-keys-in-apache---cassandra), but I would recommend secondary indexes if you are going to have a lot of columns that need to be in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to many Cassandra data modelling questions is: denormalize.

You can solve your problem by building indexes yourself. For each property have a row with the property name as key and the values and item ID as columns:

```
CREATE TABLE item_index (
  property TEXT,
  value TEXT,
  item_id TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (property, value, item_id)
)
```

you also need a table for the items:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  item_id TEXT,
  property TEXT,
  value TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (item_id, property)
)
```

(notice that in the `item_index` table all three columns are in the primary key, because I assume that multiple items can have the same value for the same property, but in the `items` table only has `item_id` and `property` in the primary key, because I assume that an item can only have one value for a property -- you can solve this for multi-valued properties too, but you have to do a few more things and it will complicate the example)

Every time you insert an item you also insert a row in the `item_index` table for each property of the item:

```
INSERT INTO items (item_id, property, value) VALUES ('thing1', 'color', 'blue');
INSERT INTO items (item_id, property, value) VALUES ('thing1', 'shoe_size', '8');
INSERT INTO item_index (property, value, item_id) VALUES ('color', 'blue', 'thing1');
INSERT INTO item_index (property, value, item_id) VALUES ('shoe_size', '8', 'thing1');
```

(you might want to insert the item as a single `BATCH` command too)

to find items by shoe size you need to do two queries (sorry, but that's the price you pay for the flexibility -- maybe someone else can come up with a solution that does not require two queries):

```
SELECT item_id FROM item_index WHERE property = 'shoe_size' AND value = '8';
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = ?;
```

where the `?` is one of the `item_id`s returned from the first query (because more than one can match, remember).